# How to combine multiple cell values in the MATCH function in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am having an excel sheet with a set of formulas and I am using Apache POI to process and evaluate the formulas. Everything is working fine except one cell which has the match formula which combines 2 other cell values. The formula is working fine in excel but the formula evaluation is not working using the Apache POI. If I am having only 1 cell value in the match formula then the Apache POI formula evaluation is working fine but it cannot process multiple cell values. Let me know how to use the conditional statement(here in my case its &) with multiple cell values and evaluate using Apache POI. Below are the 2 formulas in excel

`=MATCH(VALUE(A10),('referral sheet 2'!A1:A20),0)` -> Working in Apache POI formula evaluation

`=MATCH(VALUE(A10&A11),('referral sheet 2'!A1:A20&'referral sheet 2'!B1:B20),0)` -> Not working in Apache POI formula evaluation since combining multiple cell values

```
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency> ``
```

Comment: Please make this question a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Show the values referenced by the formula: `A10`, `A11`, `'referral sheet 2'!A1:A20`, `'referral sheet 2'!B1:B20`. And show the code which tries evaluating the formula.

Comment: Even in Excel this formula is not working very stable. `VALUE(A10&A11)` will only work if both values in `A10` and `A11` are numeric. Else it will result in `#VALUE!` error. And if both values are numeric, the concatenated value cannot be found in `'referral sheet 2'!A1:A20&referral sheet 2'!B1:B20` as `&` is a string concatenation operator. Searching a numeric value (`VALUE(A10&A11)`) in an array of strings (`'referral sheet 2'!A1:A20&referral sheet 2'!B1:B20`) will always result in `#N/A`.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, I even tried with the string values and it was not working. Could you let me know if the conditional operator works fine in Apache POI ? Because I did not see any such examples online. Also there is no issues with the java code and it is working fine when I go with single cell value. The issue is when I use the concat

Comment: Do as I told in my first comment and I will answer. If you don't, I won't answer. Answers without having the complete issue as a reproducible example are waste of time.